# Twitter API.get_user() TypeError: takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given ​

Tags: python, api, typeerror, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm still really new to coding and currently taking courses online, in which we are beginning to work with the Twitter API. I am trying to capture the ID of a Twitter account and display it below, but I keep getting this `TypeError` and can't figure out for the life of me how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. [My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PCj2.png)

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text not in an image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for sharing your code. If possible please share your code in an editable form rather than an image as it makes it easier for users to replicate your issue and help you.

Answer (score 15):

Follow the official documentation [on tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/getting_started.html#api). Please display code instead of images.

You can use:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.get_user(screen_name='dak')

print(user.id)
```

Answer (score 11):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed [`API.get_user`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/api.html#tweepy.API.get_user) to not accept any positional arguments.
The 1 positional argument being referred to in the error is `self`.
You can pass `'dak'` as the `screen_name` keyword argument instead.

Comment: Works perfectly now, Thank you!

Comment: You should [mark an answer as accepted rather than comment to say "thank you"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks man for this!